# Boolean convert from non main class to Main class

Tags: java, methods, boolean

I have a boolean method that returns true or false.
How can i use the return value and print it?

For now i have somthing like that in my main:

```
System.out.println("is the boxes are equals?   " + boxy2.equals(boxy1));
```

My Box class has following equals method (can't use toString method in this class):

```
public boolean equals(Box other){
    if (_length == other._length && _height == other._height && _width == other._width){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share your code, what you tried and the expected output.

Comment: I did add an a comment... with a code

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Can you share the error and your main method?

Comment: What's the problem with `System.out.println("is the boxes are equals? "+ boxy2.equals(boxy1));`?

Answer (score 0):

I think your already done?

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Box boxy1 = new Box(1,1);
    Box boxy1 = new Box(1,1);
    System.out.println("Are the boxes are equals? " + boxy2.equals(boxy1)  );
}

public class Box
{
    private length, width;
    public Box(int l, int w)
    {
        _length = l;
        _width = w;
    }

    public boolean equals(Box other){
        if (_length == other._length && _height == other._height && _width == other._width){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

If you wanted some customer output then use this as your print statement:

```
System.out.println("Are the boxes are equals? " +  (boxy2.equals(boxy1) ? "Yes" : "No" );
```